# SAPUI5 condition path binding for ObjectListItem

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way you can make the path of the number property of an ObjectListItem conditional?

Here's what it's doing now:

```
<ObjectListItem number="{ path: 'basket>TotalPrice', formatter: '.formatPrice'}">
```

What I need to do is set path depending on the whether `{site>/ShowPrices}` is true or false.

```
 <ObjectListItem number="{ path: = ${site>/ShowPrices} ? 'basket>TotalPrice' : '0', formatter: '.formatPrice'}">
```

E.g show the price if site>/ShowPrices is true, else show 0.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is not possible. You cannot use expression binding to assign a binding . You can either apply complex binding of parts

```
<ObjectListItem number="{ parts : [{path: 'basket>TotalPrice'},{ path : 'site>/ShowPrices'}], formatter: '.formatPrice'}">
```

or

```
<ObjectListItem number="{= ${site>/ShowPrices} ? ${basket>TotalPrice} : '0'  }">
```

You can do the conditional logic . Both will be passed to the formatter. What happens is either binding executes or formatter. The result of the logic is stored in the DOM.

Thanks and Regards,
Veera

Comment: I somehow missed you final solution, but it would work better on the visible than on the value. Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully understand what you mean by set the path and I also do not have a development environment in front of me current but if you only want to show/hide the ObjectListItem you can use a ternary operator in the visible property.

```
visible="{= ${site>/ShowPrices} === true ? true: false}"
```

I know we have used something similar for other controls but im not too fimilar with the ObjectListItem. The Visible property does not need to be part of the same model as your value is (basket).

Kind Regards,
Keith.

EDIT 
- **Miss-understood Question**. See Veeraraghavan answer.

Comment: NO can do as the ObjectListitem contains more than one parameter. I can make the whole thing visible/non-visible, but I need to do this for only one parameter (number).

Comment: I believe you can use the ObjectAttribute control inside the Object List and then hide/show this price using the visibility of the ObjectAttribute.

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. Here is some samples of the ObjectAttribute. It may not satisfy you needs but it is worth a look anyways : https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ObjectListItem/code

Comment: Thanks for that.  In your example, how do you  how do you setup expression binding on the number attribute?